# The package is not found when I want to install any programs

Tags: software-installation, mc, apt-mirror

I would like to download the midnight commander with the following task:

`sudo apt-get install mc`

But it doesn't work because the package is not found. My mirror is:

`ftp.hu.debian.org`

[image]

How can I do to install the midnhight commander?

Comment: Why would it be in there? it's in the main [repo](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/mc/download)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you've removed the standard sources. `security.debian.org` only contains *security updates*. It does not contain all packages available in Debian.

You'll need to re-add `http://ftp.xx.debian.org/` (where `xx` is your closest ISO two letter country code. E.g., us, jp, fr, etc.) to your `sources.list`.

If you need help identifying your sources, see http://debgen.simplylinux.ch

Based on your updated question, your sources should be:

```
deb http://ftp.hu.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.hu.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
```

After adding this to `/etc/apt/sources.list` run `apt-get update` before installing any packages.

Comment: I re-added the mirror but it hasn't work yet. (I corrected the question.)